# Protect Unity3D Game Data from the Rooted Mobile Devices

Tags: database, unity-game-engine, mobile, data-protection, rooted-device

Hope you are doing good. I Have a query related to Game Data(Mobile platform).
I am developing a Game in which Player has to maintain a minimum number of Experince to unlock the next level. I have been researching about the Rooted mobile devices and their usage for exploitation of the game data. Players who cannot unlock the Next level are using Rooted devices to change the Game Data(user information) and unlock the next levels. I would like to know the best way to develop the game which will not be get effected by Rooted Devices as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way to do this: game logic have to run on server (like WoW, Dota 2, etc.). Any other protection only can slow down user from altering game.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer and time.. Looking forward for more details if possible..